# Not able to establish boto3 client from inside glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

I have a python glueetl job where I am trying to call multiple AWS services. One of these services is appconfig. Per the boto3 docs, we are supposed to use the appconfigdata client to establish a session and poll for updated config. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/appconfigdata.html

However, when I try to do this within my glue job, I get an error:

```
UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'appconfigdata'. Valid service names are: accessanalyzer, ...
```

The strangest part is that outside of the glue job, when I run the exact same code on my local machine, it works fine. The code is basically

```
def fetch_appconfig():
    client = boto3.client('appconfigdata', region_name='us-east-1')
    start_session_response = client.start_configuration_session(
        ApplicationIdentifier="myappname",
        EnvironmentIdentifier="myenvname",
        ConfigurationProfileIdentifier="config_name",
    )
    configuration_token = start_session_response["InitialConfigurationToken"]
    configuration_response = client.get_latest_configuration(
        ConfigurationToken=configuration_token
    )
    config_json = (
        json.loads(configuration_response["Configuration"].read().decode("utf-8"))
    )
    client.close()
    print(config_json)
```

Why does this code fail in my glue job with the strange error but not outside?

Comment: Probably you are using old boto3 version.

Comment: What does `print(boto3.__version__)` output?

Comment: That's a good point, i will check in my next deployment. But how should I specify the boto3 version? My understanding was that boto3 was loaded by Glue natively so installing it using other means causes version clashes.

Comment: boto3 version: 1.18.50 is running in my glue job. vs 1.26.68 locally.

Comment: There you have your answer, that boto version does not support that AWS service yet.

Comment: @luk2302 sure, but I want a higher boto3 version in my glue job. so would I install it manually via extra-python-modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that my boto3 version in my glue job was outdated - as pointed out by others in the comments. To fix this, I manually installed the version of boto3 I wanted using:

```
'--additional-python-modules': 'boto3>=1.28',
```

in the glue configuration.